# How to make datalist change according to dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, webforms

I am trying to make a food webpage where I use datalist to display the food from my database and I will have a drop down list on types of cuisine example Chinese, western, Malay, Indian. How can I code my datalist such that when the user selects Malay from the dropdownlist, the datalist will show all the Malay food from database and when user selects Chinese, the datalist will change and show all the Chinese food from database.

Comment: You need to share your current code of showing food items in the datalist and showing cuisines in the dropdown list? And tag the application type also? Is it Windows Form, ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC, or mobile application? The simple logic would be to get the selected cuisine id from the dropdownlist, retrieve food items from the database for the cuisineid and rebind the datalist.

Answer (score 0):

I'am using hard coded data in my code.you can replace your database table List value Get into foodlist in PageLoad (WebForm.aspx.cs)

This is My WebForm1.aspx Html code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication8.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="All">All</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Chinese">Chinese</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="western">western</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Malay">Malay</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Indian">Indian</asp:ListItem>



    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My model

```
public class food
    {
        public int foodId { get; set; }

        public string foodName { get; set; }

        public string foodtypes { get; set; }
    }
```

WebForm.aspx.cs file

```
namespace WebApplication8
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        List<food> foodlist = new List<food>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            food fod = new food();
            fod.foodId = 1;
            fod.foodName = "testA";
            fod.foodtypes = "Chinese";

            foodlist.Add(fod);

            food fod1 = new food();
            fod1.foodId = 2;
            fod1.foodName = "testb";
            fod1.foodtypes = "Chinese";
            foodlist.Add(fod1);

            food fod3 = new food();
            fod3.foodId = 3;
            fod3.foodName = "testc";
            fod3.foodtypes = "Malay";
            foodlist.Add(fod3);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedDropdownlist = DropDownList1.Text;

            GridView1.DataSource = foodlist.Where(x => x.foodtypes == selectedDropdownlist).ToList();

            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

My UI
[image]